# Resource group not listed in Azure Network watcher IPFlow Verify

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, rdp, network-security

I am unable to RDP a VM.
So I tried to rule out any network connectivity issues by using IPFlow as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/diagnose-vm-network-traffic-filtering-problem).

However, I couldn't find my resource group in the dropdown to configure the IPFlow.
[image]
Can anyone point me on why this is happening? I have multiple VM's and resource groups.

These are my inbound rules.
[image]

Comment: its probably in a region where network watcher is not enabled?

Comment: Do you select the resource group in the right subscription?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Network watcher is enabled in that region.

Comment: @NancyXiong I have only one subscription.

Comment: clear cache\try in incognito mode?

Comment: @4c74356b41 No luck. I find the resource groups in other places. Its unavailable only here. Also, I dont find serial console. But I have owner access to the subscription.

Comment: Do you se any other resource groups? It could be a GUI issue, try to "reselect" your subscription in the subscription drop-down and/or use TAB så change fields.

Comment: I think classic resource groups don't come for IPFlow check. I created another resource group and it worked fine. Thanks every one.

Answer (score 0):

I think classic resource groups don't come for IPFlow check. I created another resource group and it worked fine. Thanks every one.